# regex match on occurrence

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a text which contains exactly 2 letters `p` in any place.

So what should match

```
pp
xppm
xpxpm
ppm
```

and what should not match

```
ppp
xpxpxp
mpphellop
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^[^p]*p[^p]*p[^p]*$
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/lE8lH7/1)

Explaining:

```
^             # from start
[^p]*         # non 'p' characters from 0 to unlimited
p             # the first 'p' character
[^p]*         # non 'p' characters from 0 to unlimited
p             # the second 'p' character
[^p]*         # non 'p' characters from 0 to unlimited
$             # till the end
```

Hope it helps.